# No envía mensaje Formulario PHP y Captcha

Tags: php, formularios, captcha, contact-form-7

Tengo el siguiente archivo con el que trato de enviar información de un formulario de contacto, la información se valida y el captcha lo hace correctamente, pero el mensaje no es recibido nunca ni a carpeta de spam. Estoy asumiendo si es que necesito agregar información adicional del servidor de mensaje, pero no estoy seguro.

```
 <?php
  if(!empty($_POST)){

  $destino = "contacto@myemail.com";
  $nombre = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $asunto = $_POST['subject'];
  $mensaje = $_POST['message'];

  $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $secret = 'key';

  if(!$captcha){
 echo'<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("Por favor verifica el captcha.");
 window.location.href="index.html#contact";
 </script>';
 }

 $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret response=$captcha");


 $arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);
 if($arr['success']){

$contenido = "Nombre: ". $nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $email ."\nAsunto: " .$asunto. "\nMensaje: " . $mensaje;
 $nombre->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

 mail($destino,  $contenido);
 echo'<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("Mensaje enviado exitosamente.");
 window.location.href="index.html";
 </script>';
 }else{
 echo'<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("ERROR al comprobar captcha.");
 window.location.href="index.html#contact";
 </script>';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué objetivo tiene esta linea? `$nombre->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: @Jonathan Orta Que reconozca caracteres especiales del nombre.

Comment: Lo más seguro es que obtengas un error en la línea que menciona @JonathanOrta, porque `$nombre` es una cadena y no un objeto al que puedas modificar propiedades. Además, te falta enviar encabezados, que es donde podrías especificar la codificación y el remitente, entre muchas otras cosas. Te recomiendo usar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), vas a poder solucionar la mayoría de problemas de recepción de correos.